# How to set a vertical slice architecture with Razor Pages?

Tags: razor-pages

By default the runtime looks for razor pages in the `Pages` folder, so you have to do this:

```
Pages
  --Orders
  ----index.cshtml
  ----add.cshtml
  --Products
  ----index.cshtml
  ----add.cshtml
```

How can I do this instead?

```
Orders
  --Pages
  ----index.cshtml
  ----add.cshtml
Products
  --Pages
  ----index.cshtml
  ----add.cshtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great idea. You need to specify one folder as the root for your Razor pages so that routing works so you still need to put your products and orders folder in that. And if you have a Pages folder in that root folder, it will become part of the route. So then you have to override all the routes that get generated by the framework unless you want to have routes like this:

```
/orders/pages/add
```

The first folder structure works fine with vertical slices. It's how I do it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Mike, I wanted to confirm that it has to be like that.

Comment: Yes, as a confirmation for @Mike, the originator of the Vertical Slice Architecture (Jimmy Bogard) has a sample repo where he uses Razor pages in just this way. His example is at https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages.